# IE9: issue in a link when use filter

Tags: css, filter, hyperlink, internet-explorer-9, gradient

My problem:I have a link with display block. Everything goes well on IE9. But when I add a filter in order to obtain a gradient, the cursor only has the hand on the border and on the text, not on the rest of the box.

I have test my code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pingoooo/SesGh/6/)

May I have done something wrong ?
My code will work on all browsers and versions. I just have delete code for other browser in order to be much clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` works "better" for IE8.
But for IE9 i would raccomend SVG gradients.

Here you can find Microsoft's official [SVG gradient background maker](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html)

You'll obtain something like this:

```
/* SVG as background image (IE9/Chrome/Safari/Opera) */ 
background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBetcetcetc);
```

And you can add it to your rule this way:

```
a {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin:5px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#FAFAFA; /* fallback for browsers not supporting gradients */
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBetcetcetc); /* FF13, Opera12, IE9 */
    background:linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #EAEAEA) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; /* W3C */
}
```

Then, with [conditional comments](http://nicolasgallagher.com/better-conditional-classnames-for-hack-free-css/) you can target IE8 again:

```
.ie8 a {
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#FAFAFA',EndColorStr='#EAEAEA'));
}
```

Anyway, i suggest you to google for "Visual CSS tool" for a complete cross-browser code.

Comment: Thanks for response and sorry for late answer, i wasn't in my job. I think using svg is really the best way to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using only `-moz-linear-gradient` and it works just for older version of Firefox Mozilla.

For IE9 you can also use `CSS3`: `linear-gradient: { ... }`

For older versions of Chrome and Safari you should use `-webkit-linear-gradient` and for Opera `-o-linear-gradient` and `-ms-` for IE (but not everything works fine with it).

Comment: Um, I don't think his issue is with the gradient itself.

Comment: I had all these lines but just cut them to make my jsfiddle a bit more little ;) This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to wrap your `a` in another `div` and apply your background properties on it instead of on the `a`;

```
<div class = "container"><a href="/">Glee is awesome!</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#FAFAFA',EndColorStr='#EAEAEA'));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #EAEAEA) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
a {
    display: block;  
}
```

Here's a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Mch8T/).

Comment: A solution, but not working for a hover effect just on the link.

Comment: @Hugo What do you mean? Can you please elaborate what effect you're trying to achieve on hover?

Comment: I have updated my fiddle. Just another gradient when hover for example.

Comment: @Hugo Well, you can use: `.container > a:hover` to change the gradient when the `a` is hovered.

Comment: @glee yes, but in your example, you change the background of the link hovered here not the container

Comment: @Hugo In that case, you can just use `.container:hover`. Here's a demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/yu8jX/).

Comment: @glee yes, already done but my problem is that the web app i'm working for is used by society who use IE6 (beuuurk I know) and IE7. These browsers don't support pseudo class :hover on anything else than a link. I think i have to do some different css files or add dynamically a class when hovered with js.

Comment: @Hugo Yeah, in that case JavaScript is the way to go.